# Suspending program to a file, then reloading it from that file

Tags: java, heap-dump

I would like to save my Java program and write its memory to a file, then be able to read that file and resume the program where it was suspended.

Are there any tools that allow me to do this? The solution only has to work on Windows. Could I somehow use Windows' hibernation feature but only hibernate a single process?

Comment: Make all of the classes that contain your program’s state serializable, then write them to a file with an ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: What you would need to be able to do is to serialise your entire state, and then unserialise it later.